# proof of the singular-values of orthogonal matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

What is a simple and intuitive proof that the singular-values of orthogonal matrix $A$ is $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singular values of a matrix, by definition, are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$.

If $A$ is orthogonal, then $A^TA = I$.

Comment: great! so the singular-values of $A$ is $\sqrt{1}$, correct?

Comment: Yep! ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Of course, $\sqrt{1} = 1$.

Comment: Yes of course :)

Comment: @hayer Sorry to spoil the fun, but Omno... is playing with you. The stated result is not true. The number $1$ has more than one square root. (You should also note that "square root of the eigenvalues of $A^TA$" is in any case not the _definition_ of the eigenvalues of $A$.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich excuse me?  By square root, I mean "principal square root".  This square root is unique.  And yes, that is the definition of the **singular values** of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry! I thought "singular value" was synonymous with "eigenvalue".

Comment: How about if the columns of A are not normalized? A is only an orthogonal matrix but not necessarily orthonormal. Does this hold? or will I end up with different values for the eigenvalues (not even constant)?

Comment: An *orthogonal* matrix, by definition, has *orthonormal* columns.  A matrix with pairwise orthogonal (but not orthonormal) columns will have different singular values and eigenvalues.

Comment: Note also that an orthogonal matrix will not necessarily have eigenvalues equal to one. However, the absolute value of all eigenvalues will be one.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Ok this is clear! thanks